# TransportError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'fieldName must not be null or empty') error happens

Tags: python, elasticsearch

TransportError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'fieldName must not be null or empty') error happens.
I am using ElasticSearch,wrote a method

```
def user_data(distance,start_time,end_time):
    param = {
     "query": {
     "bool": {
       "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": distance,
          "distance_type": "plane",
        }
      },
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "start_time": start_time
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "end_time": end_time
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
  }

  results = get_user().query(param)
```

in query method

```
def query(self, params, es_index, es_index_type, size=10000):
  results = []
  field = params.get('fields', False)
  timeout_param = "{}s".format(self._es_request_timeout)

  response = self.client().search(index=es_index, doc_type=es_index_type, scroll='5m', size=size, body=params, timeout=timeout_param)
```

I think the way of writing param is ok,so I really cannot understand why this error happens.I searched this error in Google,I found many of this error causes wrong way of writing param.Am I wrong to write query?How should I fix this?

Comment: The same query as yours is [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513263/elasticsearchs-format-error), you're missing the location field in the `geo_distance` query.